# Rookie C# problem

Tags: c#

I am a rookie to C# and here is my question

---

```
class myClass
{
    int start;
    int end;
    .......
}


class program
{

    public void main()
    {

        myClass[] a= new myClass[10];
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
        {
           myClass b = new myClass();
           a[i] = b;
           a[i].start = 1;
           ...  (keep populating)
           ...
        }
           console.writeline(a[1].start)       // NO PROBLEM WITH THIS LINE, THE VALUE WAS OUTPUTED
        subMethod(a);
    }

    public void subMethod(myClass[] a)
    {
        console.write(a[1].start);         // NO PROBLEM WITH THIS LINE, OUTPUT NORMALLY
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length, i++)
        {
            int h = a[i].start;            ????? OBJECT NOT INSTANTIATED
        }
    }
}
```

---

The error is as indicated above and I have difficulty to understand it. Anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: well it appears the array isn't properly populated, so it might help if you show the populating code you've left out

Comment: Well, four things: For one, you are skipping the first element in the array in subMethod() (don't know if that was intentional, and can't say if it has anything to do with your problem). Second, are the elements in your class public or private? Probably best to be explicit about that. Third, why is main() not static? Does this program even compile? Lastly, show us your instantiating code. That is probably where your error is.

Comment: I suspect the 'population' is in a method and the array is not passed by 'ref'

Comment: If you want an answer to your question it might be a good idea to include the parts of your code relevant to your question. You're asking why something's not instantiated and omit the instantiation code with a "populate this array" comment? C'mon, think before you post.

Comment: Why is `console.writeline` in lower case?

Comment: learn to use the (excellent & free) debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post code that compiles. The error is probably in your transcribing of the code, because this code works perfectly fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RandomArrayTest
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public int start;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass[] a = new MyClass[10];
            for(int i=1; i<a.Length; i++)
            {
                MyClass b = new MyClass();
                a[i] = b;
                a[i].start = 1;
            }

            MyFunction(a);
        }

        static void MyFunction(MyClass[] a)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                int h = a[i].start;
                Console.WriteLine(h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem seems to be in the code that you haven't posted.

```
myClass[] a= new myClass[10];
// (populate this array)
```

I've no idea what you have written there but it clearly isn't working. It should be this:

```
myClass[] a = new myClass[10];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    a[i] = new myClass();
}
```

- The code you posted won't compile. Please copy + paste the actual code - don't try to write it from memory.
- You should notice that the first index in an array is 0, not 1.
- I'd also suggest that you read the [Microsoft naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71%29.aspx), for example class names should be in Pascal case.

Answer (score 2):

You've instantiated an array but new need to instantiate each object in the array. You are not showing how you do that bit in the example above.